# What is the issue with "iterator.next()%2 "?

Tags: java, iterator, set

What is problem with my code? I am trying to find whether the set contains any odd number

```
public static boolean hasOdd (Set<Integer> set) {
    Iterator iterator;
    iterator = set.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        if(iterator.next()%2 != 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that it only checks the first element of the iterator. It should not return if the current element is even, but go to the next element. Another problem is that you should use `Iterator<Integer>`, and not just the raw `Iterator` if you want auto-unboxing to work.

It would also be more concise and readable by using a foreach loop:

```
for (Integer i : set) {
    ...
}
```

This looks like homework, or at least something you could figure out yourself, so I won't give you the solution, but only the above hints.

Comment: thank you I will try to fix it. this is not a homework. I am just working myself.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is just checking for the first element of the set and telling whether that is odd or not. However you should make sure to break from loop only when you find first Odd Number.

Comment: This is a partial solution, and not correct (hint - there were multiple problems).

Comment: And why use a Boolean when a boolean does the job?

Comment: @RichardSitze is it ok now? what are the problems you see?

Comment: Most of all, this is a textbook example how to **not answer a homework-tagged question**.

Comment: Better... you're still missing the iterator.  Really, this kinda belongs to JB at this point. :-)  I removed the down-vote anyway.

Answer (score 0):

or you can try like  this

```
Iterator<Integer> iterator = set.iterator();
```

and don't use else in loop, and false statement should be the last statement of method

Comment: ... or he can write a one-liner based on JB Nizet's suggestion. However, giving out full code is against the rules for a homework-tagged question.

Comment: hey this is not a homework. ı am working on a website:    http://webster.cs.washington.edu:8080/practiceit/ . I am trying to catch the friends which is better than me. summer is a good opportunity for this.

Comment: so, if its not homework, remove homework tag from your question.